# angular 4 observable.create not working

Tags: angular, observable

In my angular 4 app, I want to return an observable which is then subscribed.
This observable should be created only when all the items are pushed into an array(items).
This items array is been pushed when we loop through an another array(listofsubitems).

```
listofsubitems.forEach(element => {
    //do some business logic
    items.push(performlogic.validations(element));
});
const simpleObservable = new Observable((observer) => {    
    // observable execution
    observer.next(this.items)
    observer.complete()
})
```

In the subscription part, I am subscribing to this observable and assign to a spinner of type 'Subscription' which displays the spinner(busy cursor) until you finish all the items
in the listofsubitems.

When I put the observable after the forEach, I see spinner only after I see when items is populated, but I want to display when the listofsubitems are being 
processed.

How can we achieve this.

Comment: Please add the other missing code... "In the subscription part, I am subscribing to this observable..."

Comment: Here it is the subscritpnio part.                                                                                  this.someservice.simpleObservable.subscribe( (items) => {                      
                });